# Getting the number associated with a \chardef'ed control sequence

Tags: tex-core

I'd like to have access to the number associated to a box by giving its control sequence. This control sequence is defined by `\newbox` using `\chardef` so a "control sequence box" expands to something like `\char"1A`. I'd like to get that hexadecimal `1A`. Here is what I did so far.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newbox\mybox

\edef\temp{%
  \def\noexpand\stripchar\detokenize{\char"}##1\noexpand\endstripchar{##1}}
\temp

\def\printboxnumber#1{%
  \expandafter\stripchar\meaning#1\endstripchar}

\printboxnumber\mybox
\end{document}
```

The `\detokenize` is there to take care of `\catcode` change due to the use of `\meaning` in `\printboxnumber`. Unfortunately, I get

```
! Use of \stripchar doesn't match its definition.
<inserted text> \char"
                      1A
l.13 \printboxnumber\mybox
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\detokenize{\char"}` results in `\char "` (with a space after the control sequence name); you need `\string`:

```
\begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand\stripchar\string\char\string"##1\noexpand\endstripchar{##1}}
\temp
```

The second `\string` is in case **babel** is used. The `\begingroup`-`\endgroup` is to avoid leaving `\temp` defined.

The decimal representation can be obtained simply by `\number\mybox`.

Comment: `\number\mybox`... Good exercise anyway :-) Thanks for pointing out the `\detokenize` subtlety.

Comment: Every `\chardef` or `\mathchardef` token can be used when TeX is looking for a <number>. For example, the constant `\@one`, that is often used in packages, is defined as `\chardef\@ne=1`.